# State mutation in React - need an explanation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand something about React's state, deep copying of objects in JavaScript and non-mutations in functional programming in general and feel very confused at the moment due some example I ran into. It's better to show one time rather to explain a thousand times, so:

```
let arr = [
    {
        id: "a1",
        data: [
            {id: "a1b1", value: "value of a1b1"},
            {id: "a1b2", value: "value of a1b2"},
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "a2",
        data: [
            {id: "a2b1", value: "value of a2b1"},
            {id: "a2b2", value: "value of a2b2"},
        ]
    }
]

let arr2 = [...arr]
let new1 = arr2.find(item => item.id === "a2")
let new2 = new1.data.find(item => item.id === "a2b2")
new2.id = '4'
```

Now, because the `...` operator doesn't deep copy `arr`, the `arr` will be mutated as well as the `arr2` in terms of modifying the `new2.id`.

But in React, even if I do the same thing, but with `arr` being a state, the state won't get mutated... Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening and what is the appropriate way to deal with cases like this(should I deep copy, should I do something else instead?)

** Just to be more clear here, I of course do setState when I update the state and follow the React rules

Comment: I think you'd have to provide the corresponding React example and explain how you determine that the state didn't get mutated.

Comment: But it does mutate `console.log(arr[1].data)` and it will on react too, you could use `import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'`

Comment: @FelixKling There's an React dev tools for this

Comment: @Álvaro that's exactly my point... I don't see in React such behavior.

Comment: My bad... I see now it is mutated, actually... Hm... thanks for the help everyone. You were right. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react does not work on deep reference comparison. So, the moment you change the reference by doing `[...arr]` react considers it a change and updates everything dependent on it.

Also, as you mentioned that react state will not be mutated; I do not agree with it .. it will be mutated.

Comment: Are you about to tell me that when I call a function with a `const newList = [...list]`, with `list` being a state, this alone will trigger re-render/change comparison?

Comment: @ragnodisto No I did not mean that. I meant that whenever you call `setState(newList)' then as you have changed the reference; react will consider it as new list.